# Displaying "C++" in ASCII art with user inputting an integer

Tags: c++, beginner, homework, ascii-art

I have a school assignment and would love it if you can criticize or give a couple of pointers/advice about my piece of code (don't give me the answer, breaks the point of the exercise).

[image]

Here's my work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::setw;

int main()
{
//Declaring our variables
int number; //Integer input from the user

cout << " Please enter an integer :\n"; //Will display text
cin >> number; //The user's input will now be stored in the variable

//These following lines will compose the ascii art which spells out "c++"


cout << number << number << number << number << number << number << number 
<< number << number << number << number << endl; //line 1

cout << number << number << number << setw(17) << number << number << 
setw(17) << number << number << endl; // line 2

cout << number << number << number << setw(17) << number << number << 
setw(17) << number << number << endl; // line 3

cout << number << number << number << setw(12) << number << number << number 
<< number << number << number 
<< number << number << number << number << number << setw(9) << number << 
number << number << number
<< number << number << number << number << number << number << number << 
endl; //line4

cout << number << number << number << setw(17) << number << number << 
setw(17) << number << number << endl; // line 5

cout << number << number << number << setw(17) << number << number << 
setw(17) << number << number << endl; // line 6

cout << number << number << number << number << number << number << number 
<< number << number << number << number << endl; //line 7

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does target platform use monospace font? If it does not, number of spaces might need tweaking to account for different digits having different widths

Comment: @Daerdemandt That’s how [tag:ascii-art] works. I’ve never seen anyone attempt ASCII art with variable-width fonts.

Comment: @200_success please look carefully at example image in the task.

Comment: @Daerdemandt Interesting. The two pluses aren’t even the same width: the last one is wider.

Comment: Do we assume that user will input a single digit? What should we do otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Graphical representation

From your '`number << number << number`' thing it is not immediately obvious what is being drawn, and how to fix it in a specific way when needed.

By using the template where you just replace placeholder characters with what you need, you get more WYSIWYG-like result.

### Input validation

Your code assumes that user inputs appropriate value. What if user inputs `1234`? (You can get more fancy and guard against inputting non-numbers too)

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::to_string;

const auto ASCII_template = string("\
SSSSSSSSSSS\n\
SSS               SS           SS\n\
SSS               SS           SS\n\
SSS           SSSSSSSSSS   SSSSSSSSSS\n\
SSS               SS           SS\n\
SSS               SS           SS\n\
SSSSSSSSSSS");


string replace_all(const string& base_string, const string& search, const string& replace) {
  string s = string(base_string);
  size_t pos = s.find(search);
  size_t len = replace.size();
  while ( pos != string::npos ) {
     s.replace( pos, len, replace );
     pos = s.find(search);
  }
  return s;
}

unsigned int get_user_digit() {
  unsigned int result;
  do {
    cout << "Please enter a single digit:" << endl;
    cin >> result;
  } while (result >= 10);
  return result;
}

int main() {
  cout << replace_all(ASCII_template, string("S"), to_string(get_user_digit())) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

You can try it online [here](https://repl.it/L7Pq/3).

I don't remember C++ that much, but something along those lines would work. Depending on how much of С++11 you can use, `std::regex_replace` would simplify `replace_all` function. If you can not use `std::string`, it wouldn't change that much either, although you'd have to use some C-like workaround.

Comment: +1 This is a good solution, but two points: (1) you don't need line continuations in the pattern string, multiple string literals on adjacent lines are automatically concatenated, this might look clearer (2) `replace_all` could be implemented a bit more “modern“ with `std::transform`, maybe even in-place

Comment: @Thank you guys for helping me out. Sadly I can't really take your advice cause it's an introductory programming course. The TA will, of course, know that this wasn't my original idea. What I thought of doing was creating an if-else command. The program will refuse any number other than single digit numbers.

Comment: Instead of that "kickstart the cycle" hack, you should use a do-while loop instead :P

Comment: @Rakete1111 wow that's embarassing:) Fixed

Comment: @FelixDombek (1) I'll still need `"\n"`s, so no biggie. (2) `std::transform` looks super-good indeed (although not available on repl.it). Still, `replace_all` works on *substring* level, not *char* level. It's an overkill, but more reusable and realistically I'll just copy-paste / import it from somewhere where I've already written it. As for in-place - personal preference against side-effects)

Comment: @Daerdemandt try `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: @FelixDombek Thanks, [works like a charm](https://repl.it/L7Pq/4).

Answer (score 2):

1. Good thing you didn't use `using namespace std;`! :)
2. I would indent the code in `main`, but maybe that's because you pasted the code here.
3. Remove unnecessary comments:

   ```
   //Declaring our variables
   int number;
   ```

   Of course you're declaring a variable, you don't need to write it again.
4. Use better names so you don't need comments:

   ```
   int number; //Integer input from the user
   ```

   Instead, why not use `int user_input;` or similar, that way, you don't need the comment. Or leave it be (but remove the comment).
5. `std::endl`, along with outputting a newline, flushes the stream, which can be quite costly (although it doesn't matter for non-performance critical pieces of code like yours). Just use `'\n'` instead if you don't need the flush (on some platforms you might need it).
6. Technically, you don't need to `return 0;`, as the compiler will do that for you if you omit it.

Those huge lists of `std::cout`'s bother me a bit. It would be better if you could refactor it to a function. I would do it [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fedbcf760f6e5436).

Answer (score 0):

One thing about programming is also to reduce duplication.

So looking at the required output we can notice, that you have 3 unique lines of text.

So an idea would be to preconstruct these 3 lines of text. 
Maybe into string variables or make 3 functions returning these strings or 3 functions outputing theses varaibles or ...  .

Then output the variables or call the functions in the required order.